# Retrieve elements values from external page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cordova

i am working on a phonegap application that contains a page for live price and this page update every 5 seconds. this page is writed in php script so i can't import the code to the application bescause it dosen't work. i try jQuery .load() method but it seemes that it needs to be run on a server to activate the script so it wont work on phonegap application.
is there any other way to retrieve the elements using only HTML5 and JavaScript to do this task?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly are you trying to do. But If you can use php, definitely use it! Something like this:

```
function get_data($url) {
   $ch = curl_init();
   $timeout = 10;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);


  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data; 
}

$page = "http://yourwebsite.whatever";    
$html =  get_data($page);
```

And pars what you need from `$html`.

Comment: i canot use php in phonegap app because php is server side script and phonegap is client side, i did use iframe but this not a recommended solution, i want to know is there any way other than use php.